# Como capturar tamanho arquivo de System.Drawing.Image?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, arquivo, drawing

Tenho um método ao qual passo o parâmetro `System.Drawing.Image` e o percentual que irá ficar essa imagem após o *resize*.

```
public static Image ResizeImagem(Image imgFoto, int percentual)
{
  float nPorcentagem = ((float)percentual / 100);

  int fonteLargura = imgFoto.Width;     //armazena a largura original da imagem origem
  int fonteAltura = imgFoto.Height;   //armazena a altura original da imagem origem
  int origemX = 0;        //eixo x da imagem origem
  int origemY = 0;        //eixo y da imagem origem

  int destX = 0;          //eixo x da imagem destino
  int destY = 0;          //eixo y da imagem destino
  //Calcula a altura e largura da imagem redimensionada
  int destWidth = (int)(fonteLargura * nPorcentagem);
  int destHeight = (int)(fonteAltura * nPorcentagem);

  //Cria um novo objeto bitmap
  Bitmap bmImagem = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
  //Define a resolu~ção do bitmap.
  bmImagem.SetResolution(imgFoto.HorizontalResolution, imgFoto.VerticalResolution);
  //Crima um objeto graphics e defina a qualidade
  Graphics grImagem = Graphics.FromImage(bmImagem);
  grImagem.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

  //Desenha a imge usando o método DrawImage() da classe grafica
  grImagem.DrawImage(imgFoto,
      new Rectangle(destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight),
      new Rectangle(origemX, origemY, fonteLargura, fonteAltura),
      GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

  grImagem.Dispose();  //libera o objeto grafico
  return bmImagem;
}
```

Mas eu preciso pegar o tamanho desse arquivo, em *bytes* para que eu execute o `Resize` até a imagem ter 200KB.

Comment: Você precisa do tamanho de um arquivo qualquer, certo? Tem algum motivo especial para que isto esteja relacionado diretamente ao `System.Drawing.Image`?

Comment: @bigown, tenho um método que recebe Image, vou postar

Comment: @bigown Editei a pergunta, acho que ficou mais claro

Comment: Acho que não. Ou não ajudou nada ou confirmou o que eu dizia, não importa o que tem neste arquivo, você quer o tamanho dele e ponto. Ficaria mais claro se mostrar que ser imagem faz diferença. Eu vou responder o que acho que resolve o problema. Se não for isto, você fala e tento melhorar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que entendi o que você precisa é saber o tamanho de um arquivo qualquer. Não faz diferença o que tem dentro dele. O resultado não será diferente se tiver um texto, uma imagem, uma estrutura de banco de dados, uma música ou qualquer outra coisa.

Para isto você usa a classe `FileInfo` e pega o [`Length`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.length?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_FileInfo_Length). basicamente é isto:

```
long tamanho = new System.IO.FileInfo(path).Length; //path é o caminho completo do arquivo.
```

Mas se precisar pegar esta informação ainda em memória pode fazer algo assim:

```
long tamanho;
using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream()) {
    imgFoto.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    tamanho = ms.Length;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/ImageLength.cs).

Escolha o formato que deseja "salvar" a imagem. Escolha em [`ImageFormat`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#properties). Note que isto não está salvando em arquivo em disco. Não posso garantir que após o salvamento em disco seja exatamente o mesmo tamanho. Pode haver alguma pequena variação, bem pequena mesmo.

Comment: ,o código realmente pegou o tamanho que eu queria, porém ao fazer um While, e ir rendenizando ela, acho que ela está salvando no mesmo MemorySteam, e somando valores, como poderia fechar o MemoryStream e abri-lo novamente ?

Comment: Depende da maneira como está fazendo. Se usar exatamente isto, está fechando todas as vezes. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx. Provavelmente você seu código dentro do `using`, aí vai dar problema. Este código é para ser usado em si só. A única coisa que ele se relaciona com o resto do seu código é o uso da `imgFoto` que já deve existir. Se ainda assim estiver ocorrendo algo errado, o problema está neste objeto que está sendo reaproveitado ao invés de gerar um novo. Aí o problema já seria outro, nada relacionado à sua pergunta.

Comment: Entendi @bigown, bom, então sabendo aonde está o erro, verei aqui, obrigado

Comment: É possível (embora ache que não) que o problema esteja neste `grImagem.Dispose();`. Na verdade acho que pode estar relacionado. Isto é uma prática errada. Se acontecer qualquer problema o código ele nunca será chamado. É provável que você tenha usado este padrão em outros lugares e esteja causando problemas. O `Dispose()` nunca deve ser chamado em código a não ser que você tem um motivo muito forte para isto. Sua chamada deve ser garantida pela linguagem, por isto usei o `using`, ele garante isto. O `bmImagem` nem o `Dispose()` faz. Você está deixando lixo por toda a memória.

Comment: tentei setar como Null, mas irei tentar aqui, obrigado

Comment: só um feedback, o erro estava no MemoryStream, sempre que fazia Imagem.Save(ms,Imageformart.jpeg) ele salvava no memoryStream, então eu setei ele como null e e instanciava novamente para ter um novo espaço na memória

Comment: isto está errado, quase nunca existe um motivo para setar `null` para algo existente. Você até pode ter consertado o problema na força bruta mas tem erro aí. Como não estou vendo seu código não posso dar detalhes mas você usou de alguma forma que está reaproveitando o objeto e este é o erro. Do jeito que eu postei não deveria fazer isto.

Comment: meu código está assim: http://pastebin.com/s77N5btP caso queira dar alguma opinião

Comment: Você não usou o `MemoryStream` do jeito que eu te passei. Você tirou o fechamento dele. Deixou a memória vazar. pra falar a verdade esse código está causando um caos na memória.

Comment: Veja que no While, eu faço o seguinte, eu converto a Imagem e adiciono ela para o MemoryStream, até que ele fique com o tamanho passado de KB, usando Using, ele ficava adicionando a Imagem toda vez no MemoryStream, fazendo com que o tamanho dele sempre aumentase e não diminuise como eu queria...Não sei outra solução para isso